Inverse of Shifted Wishart $(I+W)^{-1}$
Consider the classical Wishart distribution of dimension $n$ on $p$ features. In other words, if $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix and $G \sim N(0, \Sigma)$, then the Wishart distribution is that of the $p \times p$ matrix $W = G G^t$.
I am trying to calculate the expectation of $(I+W)^{-1}$ over the Wishart distribution $W \sim N(0, \Sigma)$.
I first encountered the expression when I was trying to compute loss minimizers under the assumption of Gaussian data, and it also appears in doing computations of data 'perturbation'. A related expectation that appears which is well known that $E[W^{-1}] = \frac{\Sigma}{n-p-1}$.
One way I have tried is to express this as a sum of powers of $W$ by the "geometric series" (when convergence holds) $$(I+W)^{-1} = \sum_{k \ge 0} (-W)^k$$and use the works of Nagar, Gupta et al. for means of moments of Wishart matrices $E[W^k]$. However, the exact computation of moments is very complicated, and I tried to find something which avoids the infinite summation but I couldn't make any progress.
